# NoSuchMethodError ResponseEntity$BodyBuilder

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement web sockets to listen to a server for messages. I've made a sample project which works successfully and I'm now trying to port it over to our existing code base. When I run the application I get the following error:

```
2019-08-29 09:34:33 - org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient: [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR - Initial SockJS "Info" request to server failed, url=ws://localhost:8080/igip-gateway/messaging
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.status(I)Lorg/springframework/http/ResponseEntity$BodyBuilder;
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport.lambda$static$1(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:158) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:496) ~[org.springframework.web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:465) ~[org.springframework.web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport.executeInfoRequestInternal(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:137) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractXhrTransport.executeInfoRequest(AbstractXhrTransport.java:129) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.getServerInfo(SockJsClient.java:294) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.doHandshake(SockJsClient.java:260) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:268) [spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:249) [spring-websocket-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

I can see the method exists as a class in an external library as part of `spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar` and when I run the application with `verbose:class` the only references I can see to that jar are:

```
[Loaded org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder from file:/C:/DEV/m2/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.http.converter.json.SpringHandlerInstantiator from file:/C:/DEV/m2/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.http.HttpLogging from file:/C:/DEV/m2/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar]
```

Here is my code as well in case it's relevant:

```java
    private static String URL = "ws://localhost:8080/gateway/messaging";

    public static void start() {
        StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(webSocketClient));
        WebSocketClient client = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Heart-Beat-Executor-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        stompClient.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);

        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());

        StompHeaders connectHeaders = new StompHeaders();
        connectHeaders.setHeartbeat(new long[]{20000, 20000});
        connectHeaders.add("SECURITY-TOKEN", "token");

        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new CallListeningStompSessionHandler();
        ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect = stompClient.connect(URL, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), connectHeaders, sessionHandler);
        System.out.println(connect);
    }
```

```java
    public class CallListeningStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
            StompHeaders connectHeaders = new StompHeaders();
            connectHeaders.add("SECURITY-TOKEN", "token");
            connectHeaders.add("destination", "/topic/services/user");
            session.subscribe(connectHeaders, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        }

        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            System.out.println(payload);
        }

    }
```

What is the reason I am getting this error?

Comment: Add your POM/Gradel file. Generally this is caused by mixing versions of Spring Framework/Spring Boot

Comment: It's... prohibitively long... Is there a way I can specify the version I want it to use? Use specified rather than transitive?

Comment: If you can add your depenendencies at least? If you are using Spring Framework and mixing versions you should use some sort of dependency mgmt. For spring framework, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom. With spring boot there is more options.

Comment: I used the intelliJ plugin Dependency Analyzer and there were indeed conflicts between `spring-web`. I've removed all the conflicts and deleted the old version directory from my m2 folder but I still get the error.